# Comparing elements from two lists/tuples with a for loop (in a recursion)

Tags: python, loops, recursion, matrix, tuples

This is actually part of a much longer recursion but all I'm trying to figure out is if I'm writing this line wrong:

```
for i in range(len(colors):
    if colors[i][j] == new_pfx[-1][j] for j in range(1, len(colors[i])):
        continue
    else:
        (there is an append here)
```

basically:

- "new_pfx" is a list where I'm recursively appending tuples (tuples length stays the same throughout the recursion but the code must work for any length)
- "colors" is another list of tuples (again, same length)

what I'm trying to do is:
to exclude from the append (with "continue") every tuple from "colors" where an element inside it (excluding the first and last) is equal to the element with the same index in the last tuple from "new_pfx".

Is my syntax wrong?

It's hard for me to post my results because this is part of a much larger program and I simplified it for this post. Hope I was clear, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You should be using the `any()` function: `if any(colors[i][j] ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a generator as a bool on its own.  What I think you want is `any`:

```
if any(colors[i][j] == new_pfx[-1][j] for j in range(1, len(colors[i])-1)):
```

(note that if you want to exclude the last element as well as the first, you want `range(1, len(colors[i])-1)`)

You can also do this entire loop more simply by iterating over the lists directly rather than using the `i` and `j` indices:

```
for color in colors:
    if any(c == n for c, n in zip(color[1:-1], new_pfx[-1][1:-1])):
        continue
    # there is an append here, using color instead of colors[i]
```